# Select specific value from Hive array

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a table in Hive structured with 3 columns as follows;

```
timestamp   UserID  OtherId    
2016-09-01  123     "101","222","321","987","393.1","090","467","863"
2016-09-01  124     "188","389","673","972","193","100","143","210"
2016-09-01  125     "888","120","482","594","393.2"
2016-09-01  126     "441","501","322","671","008","899"
2016-09-01  127     "004","700","393.4","761","467","356","643","578"
2016-09-01  128     "322","582","348"
2016-09-01  129     "029","393.8","126","187"
```

Where OtherID is an array.

I need to parse OtherID so that the resultant dataset is the following, since I am only interested in values which contain '393%'

```
timestamp   UserID  OtherId    
2016-09-01  123     393.1
2016-09-01  125     393.2
2016-09-01  127     393.4
2016-09-01  129     393.8
```

I have researched a ton of parse functions but it seems they're all intended to return the position of the value, or you need to specify the position of the value to return it. Both of these options do not work here because '3309%' can occur at any point in the array for any given row.
There's also the fact that I need to incorporate the wildcard to allow for variations of my desired value.

Another option is explode but my table is simply too large for that option.

I'm thinking a UDF might be the only way to go but would welcome some guidance there.

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Could you try something like this? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE OtherId RLIKE regexp_extract(OtherId, '(\"393\.\d\")', 1)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Gives following error: "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 2:19 Wrong arguments ''(\"393\.\d\")'': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with (array<string>, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string) _FUNC_(string, string, int)"

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that OtherId is an array, not a string. Maybe Hive has a native function that could somehow "combine" the array elements so that you could use a regex...

Comment: Hang on, would this only work on string? You see OtherID was a string before I used a function to make it an array because I assumed that would make it easier to handle. Should I apply your regex suggestion to a string instead?

Comment: Yes, please try it with a string instead. How are the numbers separated within the string? Are they comma-separated ? like `"101,222,321"` Or do they have spaces in-between? Depending on that, I have to modify the regex a little bit

Comment: Cool, I'll try it on the original string. The values are actually colon separated. So they look like '393.9:289:578:' etc. Difficult to assess, hence my decision to transform into an array.

Comment: Ok, try with this one instead: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE OtherId RLIKE regexp_extract(OtherId, '(^|:)(393\.\d)($|:)', 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy do what you need using the lateral view option available in hive.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default> select * from test_5; 
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| test_5.t  | test_5.id  |                  test_5.oid                  |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 123       | 123        | "222","321","987","393.1","090","467","863"  |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And this is the trick:

```
SELECT id, ooid
FROM test_5 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(oid,",")) temp AS ooid;

+------+----------+
|  id  |   ooid   |
+------+----------+
| 123  | "222"    |
| 123  | "321"    |
| 123  | "987"    |
| 123  | "393.1"  |
| 123  | "090"    |
| 123  | "467"    |
| 123  | "863"    |
+------+----------+
```

Ergo:

```
SELECT id, regexp_replace(ooid,'"','')
FROM test_5 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(oid,",")) temp AS ooid;
WHERE ooid LIKE '"393%';

+------+----------+
|  id  |   ooid   |
+------+----------+
| 123  |  393.1   |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try as below:

```
hive> select timestamp1, userid, otherids from userdet1 LATERAL VIEW explode(otherid) testTable as otherids where otherids LIKE concat('393','%');
```

OK

```
2016-09-01  123 393.1

2016-09-01  125 393.2

2016-09-01  127 393.4

2016-09-01  129 393.8

Time taken:  0.297  seconds,  Fetched: 4 row(s)
```